# PDF of an unknown probability after a successful test.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable having the possible outcomes $\{0, 1\}$ representing failure or success, with unknown probability. We test $X$ just one time and the outcome is success. Let $X(1) = p \in [0, 1]$, ie, $p$ is the probability that another test of $X$ will be successful. Is it possible to find a probability density function for $p$? If so, how could this distribution be described?

Intuitively it would seem that $P(p = 0) = 0$, and $P(p > \frac{1}{2}) > P(p < \frac{1}{2})$, for example.

This question is very similar to the unanswered [Unknown Probabilities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443900/unknown-probabilities), but that question was asked over a year ago and takes the problem in a slightly different direction.

Comment: A PDF for $p$ implicitly states that $p$ is a random variable. In this context it can highly be looked at as a constant rv. Underlying you could construct a rv $P$ taking values in $[0,1]$ and use the outcomes of the tests to gather information about its distribution.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand so I will attempt to explain your comment to myself. $p$ could be considered a constant rv specific to $X$ and so it is not accurate to talk about a PDF for $p$. Rather, I should define a rv $P \in [0, 1]$ that is the $p$ of a random rv from the set of all rvs defined in the same way as $X$. Yes?

Comment: You are close. My thinking (nothing more): let there be some (unknown) distribution on measurable space $[0,1]$. Let $P_1,P_2,\dots$ be iid rvs equipped with this distribution. Let $X_i$ take value $1$ with probability $P_i$, i.e $P(X_i=1|P_i=p)=p$ or $E(X_i|P_i)=P_i$. Then based on the outcomes for $X_i$ you can e.g. test hypotheses on the distribution of the $P_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I have an idea here.

Let P(1) denote the probability of the first outcome being a success. If $p$ is given then $P(1)=p$, but since $p$ is unknown and different values of $p$ are mutually exclusive events with probabilities $f(p)dp$:

$$
P(1) = \int p{f(p) dp} = \int {pd(F(p))}\\ = pF(p) - \int{F(p)dp}
$$

Let $g(p)= \int Fdp$, and $P(1)=a$, constant.Then $g'-g/p=a/p$. I multiply the homogenous equation by an integration factor $M(p)=1/p$ to get

$$
g_h'-\frac{1}{p}g_h=0 \\
\frac{1}{p}g_h'-\frac{1}{p^2}g_h=0 \\
\frac {d}{dp} \left( \frac{g_h}{p}\right) = 0 \\
g_h = cp
$$

The obvious partial solution is $g_p(p)=a$ so $g= g_h+g_p = cp+a$.

This is where I'm stuck. $F(p)=g'(p)=c$, but this doesn't make sense. I think my initial assertion that $P(1) = \int p{f(p) dp}$ is correct, but I can't spot the error in the math.